# Modulo in Subtracting using identities

Tags: c++, modulo

In the various modulo identities, the subtraction identity states that:

```
(a - b) % c = (a % c - b % c) % c
```

But if I look at this example where `a = 508, b = 201 and c = 101`, the answer I get using the identity is negative, which is not correct. My program in c++ uses factorial of huge numbers (doesn't start from 1, but from user given input to another number) modulo `10^9 + 7` minus another factorial number (less than the first value) mod  `10^9 + 7` but I get negative values, or overflows while using unsigned long long.

Is there any possible implementation to get the correct output?

Comment: What functionality is represented by `$`?

Comment: Search the internet for "StackOverflow C++ mod large numbers".

Comment: Show some small example code that illustrates your issue.  **Post as Text**, no screen snapshots.  Screen snapshots are difficult to paste into an IDE so we can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: The $ is the latex format.

Comment: If `a`, `b` and `c` are all positive (or zero, for `a` and `b`), and you want to avoid a negative value from `(a%c - b%c) % c`, then just add another `c` to the subtraction - i.e. `(c + a%c - b%c) % c`.

Comment: a negative number is a valid result.basically you are operating on a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics). your negative number is in the same equivalence class as itself + the modulus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I guess it should be as follows

`((a%c - b%c) % c + c) % c`

If `a = 12`, `b = 7` and `c = 10` then
`(a%c - b%c)%c` will give -5
Then adding `c` and mod it again will result in 5 which is correct answer

Comment: This doesn't always work if any of `a`, `b`, or `c` are negative.